# Could you write a printf wrapper that interleaves formatting code and arguments?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I like the succinct format specifiers that printf offers such as %1.3f, as compared to cout, but hate how you have to put all the variables you are going to print at the end of the argument list, which is prone to errors whenever you want to add a new item to be printed. Here's what I'd like to do. Instead of

`printf("\n\n%ix%i%c %1.2f\n",sw, sh, interlaced, refresh);`

I'd like

`printf("\n\n%i", sw, "x%i", sh, "%c ", interlaced, "%1.2f\n", refresh);`

It seems like this should be possible with the right wrapper function, but writing variable argument functions is a black art to me. Or has somebody already written this? It seems like such an obvious idea.

Comment: You will need to define a new format string specifier for the subsequent format string arguments.

Comment: I think this is possible using variadic arguments and variadic templates.

Comment: But what if I want the format string to be built dynamically, and not be interspersed with actual variables at the `printf` call site?

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want `printf`s with too many arguments, you can always break it into several `printf`s.

Comment: The issues is what `printf` is expecting as its parameters.  My understanding is that `printf` wants format specifiers first, then a comma separated list of variables.  The `printf` is not expecting another format specifier string.

Comment: [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format).  That is the modern C++ 20 way of doing this.  But as you can see, it has the same pattern -- format string first, then variables come later.  Interleaving format string with the variables -- very few, if anyone has needed to create such a wrapper.

Comment: If you are looking for something like C#'s [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), it doesn't exist in C++. `std::format()` is cleaner and safer than `printf()`, but still follows the same pattern. But [`fmt::format()`](https://fmt.dev) extends the [format string](https://fmt.dev/latest/syntax.html) to support *named arguments*, at least.

Comment: C#'s string interpolation is a decent solution to the problem I'm trying to solve, but obviously that specific method is beyond what's possible in plain C.

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++? Remove the other from tags, please.

Comment: Al Ro, Yes.  Similar C effort: [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) writes via interleaving format codes and arguments.

Comment: in fact the C++ solution is in most ways the most elegant, despite it being in no way class oriented. I think it's fair to keep the tags as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Could you write a `printf` that interleaves formatting code and arguments?*  Yes, sort of.  But not by writing any kind of a "wrapper" around `printf`.  To do it at all (and due to what you called the "black art" of varargs functions), we would have to write our own version of this "multi printf", from scratch.

Also there's a complication in that it will be hard for multi-printf to know when it's done.  Normally, `printf` reads exactly one format string, and then for each `%` in the format string, it expects (usually) one more argument.  If we want a version that can read a format string, and some arguments, and then another format string, and then some more arguments, how will it know when it's done?  After processing one format string, and its arguments, how will our multi-printf know whether or not it should look for an additional format string?

Remember, the rule is that a varargs function must be able to tell, *from the arguments it fetches*, how many arguments it should expect (and of what type).  There's no independent way for it to know how many arguments were actually passed this time.

So the multi-printf I'm going to implement here is slightly different than the one you imagined.  It takes any number of format strings, interspersed with arguments, *but* the last format string must either have no additional arguments (contain no `%` signs), or it must be a null pointer.

This code is a modification of the `miniprintf` function from [question 15.4](http://c-faq.com/varargs/varargs1.html) of the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).  Please refer to question 15.4 and make sure you have a basic grasp of how the `miniprintf` function there works.  (That question and others in [section 15](http://c-faq.com/varargs) should dispel at least some of the "black magic" concerning varargs functions; see also [chapter 25](https://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx11.html) of my C course notes.)  Essentially, I'm taking the format-parsing and argument-interpolating code from `miniprintf`, and slapping a `do`/`while` loop around it so that it can parse an arbitrary number of additional format strings per call.

Here's the code.  It requires a "helper" function, `baseconv`, from [question 20.10](http://c-faq.com/misc/hexio.html) of the FAQ list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
multiprintf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    const char *p;
    int i;
    unsigned u;
    char *s;
    va_list argp;

    va_start(argp, fmt);

    do {
        int nperc = 0;

        for(p = fmt; *p != '\0'; p++) {

            if(*p != '%') {
                putchar(*p);
                continue;
            }

            nperc++;

            switch(*++p) {
                case 'c':
                    i = va_arg(argp, int);
                    putchar(i);
                    break;

                case 'd':
                    i = va_arg(argp, int);
                    if(i < 0) {
                        i = -i;
                        putchar('-');
                    }
                    fputs(baseconv(i, 10), stdout);
                    break;

                case 'o':
                    u = va_arg(argp, unsigned int);
                    fputs(baseconv(u, 8), stdout);
                    break;

                case 's':
                    s = va_arg(argp, char *);
                    fputs(s, stdout);
                    break;

                case 'u':
                    u = va_arg(argp, unsigned int);
                    fputs(baseconv(u, 10), stdout);
                    break;

                case 'x':
                    u = va_arg(argp, unsigned int);
                    fputs(baseconv(u, 16), stdout);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(nperc == 0) break;
    
        fmt = va_arg(argp, char *);

    } while(fmt != NULL);

    va_end(argp);
}
```

And here's a test program to call it:

```
int main()
{
    int sw = 12;
    int sh = 0;
    int interlaced = 'A';
    multiprintf("%d ", sw, "x%d ", sh, "%c\n", interlaced, NULL);
    char *s = "four";
    multiprintf("int: %d ", sw, "char: %c ", '3', "string: %s", s, "\n");
}
```

Now, although this code does answer your question, I have to say I have pretty grave doubts that it would really end up being that useful in practice.  `printf` is already hard enough to call correctly.  Many programmers have difficulty keeping the number (and especially the types) of the extra arguments right, and this new function only exacerbates those difficulties.  It would be hard to remember to keep the last format argument %-free.  (It might make sense to define an additional termination condition, namely that it would look for another format string only if the previous one didn't end with `\n`.)

Also, a few more disclaimers:

1. Like the FAQ list's `miniprintf`, the version I've shown is stripped-down and incomplete: it doesn't do floating-point (`%e` or `%f` or `%g`), it doesn't do field widths or precisions, it doesn't return a proper value, etc., etc.
2. Strictly speaking, if you want to use a null pointer to terminate the format list here, you have to use the syntax `(char *)NULL`; you can't use plain `NULL`.  (See [question 5.11](http://c-faq.com/null/nullreq.html) in the FAQ list for the reason.)

---

The other possibility to contemplate is, what if you could embed variable names directly in the format string?  Going back to your original example, what if you could write it as something like

```
interpolatingprintf("%{sw:i} x%{sh:i} %{interlaced:c} %{refresh:1.2f}");
```

The problem, of course, is that this could never work with `interpolatingprintf` as a "regular" function.  This sort of thing would require compiler support, to parse the format string and pick out the variable names so that they could be evaluated and passed.  (Also one wonders if things like `interpolatingprintf("%{a+b:d}")` could or should be allowed.)

---

Finally, for completeness, since Stack Overflow answers are supposed to be standalone, here's the `baseconv` code from the FAQ list's [question 20.10](http://www.c-faq.com/misc/hexio.html):

```
char *baseconv(unsigned int num, int base)
{
    static char retbuf[33];
    char *p;

    if(base < 2 || base > 16)
        return NULL;

    p = &retbuf[sizeof(retbuf)-1];
    *p = '\0';

    do {
        *--p = "0123456789abcdef"[num % base];
        num /= base;
    } while(num != 0);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice start of an implementation. I would argue that the only reason this seems error prone to you is the lack of familiarity to this form. Having spent many years using interpreted languages where argument interleaving is the default I find it much more natural than having to count commas at the end of the printf function to determine where to insert the new variable that I want to print.  That is to say, calling printf is easy enough the first time, but a pain when you come back and modify it later.

Comment: Plus this puts the format specifier right next to the variable you are printing - how could that be bad? I fail to see how the current method where the variables to print all get shuffled to the end of the function is less error prone, other than the serious advantage that compilers currently know how to check it to some extent.  In any case, to each their own!

Comment: @AlRo Glad you liked.  See also [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11.html).  That note about "grave doubts that it would really end up being that useful in practice" was mostly to head off critics who otherwise would have said the same thing.  I'm mostly okay with it, except for the weird rule about the last format (but only the last format) needing to contain no `%` signs.  I wanted to make `multiprintf("Hello ", "world!\n")` work, but it doesn't (and can't).

Comment: There's little reason to offer multiple non-format string support. After all, you can just remove the comma and the C compiler will join those strings for you. I would say that for consistency I'd enforce a trailing null argument, rather than the no % heuristic. multiprint("mean: %1.2f ", mean, "median: %1.2f\n", median, NULL);

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
printf("\n\n");
printf("%i", sw);
printf("x%i", sh);
printf("%c ", interlaced);
printf("%1.2f", refresh);
printf("\n");
```

Comment: OP, this is probably the best way to go tbh. Overloading printf like what you want is going to be nasty arcane code that nobody will ever be able to debug. As Robin Dillen mentioned, you'll at least need to use variadic arguments, which are a nasty mess in the best of cases.

Comment: Ok, fair point. But very verbose. I suppose you could write a macro to do the expansion.

Comment: And get back to the square one with a mess of alternating parameters? (this time to the macro)

Comment: Variadic arguments are not so difficult and arcane as people want to believe.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using C++, you could potentially do this like:

```cpp
template<typename ... Args, std::size_t ... N>
void myPrint_impl(std::tuple<Args...> tup, std::index_sequence<N...>)
{
    (std::printf(std::get<N * 2>(tup), std::get<N * 2 + 1>(tup)), ...);
}

template<typename ... Args>
void myPrint(Args ... args)
{
    return myPrint_impl(std::make_tuple(args...), std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(args) / 2>{});
}

int main()
{
    myPrint("\n\n%i", 10, "x%i", 20, "%c ", 'o', "%1.2f\n", 1.234);
}
```

Comment: Is this actually valid c++ code or just the basic gist? I'm more interested in a C answer than C++, and am not qualified to judge if it's correct, but this approach is intriguing nonetheless.

Comment: @AlRo I'm not familiar with C, but this is valid C++ code, demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jWq4nsPsr

Comment: That's really cool, thanks for sharing. Maybe it's time to revisit C++ as a better C...

Comment: If I were allowed to accept multiple answers I would choose this one too, but since it's not vanilla C I can't really promote it over the other full answer. Nonetheless thanks for contributing.

Comment: One issue here is that arguments that don't come as pairs get lost. There's no necessity to support sending 3 arguments to myPrint, but it would be nice if it gave a compile error, or something rather than compiling ok and silently ignoring the 3rd augment.

Comment: @AlRo With C++20, you can simply add a constraint `requires (sizeof...(Args) % 2 == 0)` to `myPrint` to give compiler error when there odd numbers of argument: https://godbolt.org/z/KTTd3a4cW For earlier versions, you would likely do it with SFINAE

Comment: @AlRo And you can also use `static_assert` to make sure each odd argument is `const char*`: https://godbolt.org/z/v8axGePKs

Comment: That's great. Obviously C++ metaprogramming has come a long way.

Answer (score 2):

For a strictly C answer, *yes* you can, but people don’t because the problem becomes *when do the arguments end?*

A normal format specifier string matches specifiers in both *number* and *type* to the arguments that follow. When there are no more specifiers, any remaining arguments (should there be any) are simply ignored.

But if you want to interleave, then you must have a terminal argument, such as NULL, in order to signal end-of-arguments. Your interleaved printf would then look like this:

```
iprintf( "%d", my_int, "%s", "my string", "%f", my_float, NULL );
```

That last `NULL` argument is the thorn that people don’t like, in large part because it can be accidentally forgotten, leading to UB code!

<sup>Consequently, I will *not* present a solution for the above syntax.</sup>

#### Evil Macros to the Rescue

Yes, we’re not done. It is entirely possible to create the syntax you like by abusing the C preprocessor! The good news is that this also solves the UB problem with non-terminal argument lists.

The bad news is that it takes a lot of LOC to make it happen: specifically, you must declare your magic function and then override its declaration with macros, which is an evil thing to do, as the macros have no awareness of context and could clobber something totally unrelated.

<s>(It will take me a few minutes to design and test some code for you.)</s>

EDIT: heh, actually, I really don’t want to rewrite printf tonight... (because that is what is needed, basically). In other words, this weird syntax *can* be done, but no one wants to. I don’t.

### Meh, evil macros + first solution for the <s>win</s>!

So, this question has suddenly become very popular, it seems. IDK *why* anyone would want to do this, but here you go: `multi_printf` and family:

```
// ABSOLUTELY NOT FULLY TESTED!
// NOT FOR PRODUCTION CODE!
// (Why would you do this anyway?)

#include <errno.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int multi_vsnprintf(
  char       * buffer,
  size_t       size,
  const char * format,
  va_list      args )
{
  int result = 0;

  while (format and ((size-result > 0) or !buffer))
  {
    // This is the easy part: make the C standard library do all the work

    va_list args2;
    va_copy( args2, args );
    int n = vsnprintf( buffer ? buffer+result : NULL, buffer ? size-result : 0, format, args2 );
    va_end( args2 );

    // If anything went wrong we need to quit now to propagate the error result upward,
    // otherwise we just keep accumulating the number of characters output

    if (n < 0)
    {
      result = n;
      break;
    }
    result += n;

    // Now for the obnoxious part: skip args to find the next format string
    // This only understands standard C99 argument types and modifiers!
    // (POSIX throws some others in there too, methinks, etc. We ignore them.)

    for (const char * p = strchr( format, '%' );  p and *p;  p = strchr( p+1, '%' )) do
    {
      p = strpbrk( p+1, "%*csdioxXufFeEaAgGnp" );
      switch (*p)
      {
        case '%':
          break;

        case '*':
          va_arg( args, int );
          continue;

        case 'c': //if (p[-1] == 'l') va_arg( args, wint_t ); else va_arg( args, int       ); break;
                  va_arg( args, int );
                  break;
        case 's': if (p[-1] == 'l') va_arg( args, char * ); else va_arg( args, wchar_t * ); break;

        case 'd': case 'i': case 'o': case 'x': case 'X': case 'u':
          switch (p[-1])
          {
            case 'l': if (p[-2] == 'l') va_arg( args, long long );
                      else              va_arg( args, long      ); break;
            case 'j':                   va_arg( args, intmax_t  ); break;
            case 'z':                   va_arg( args, size_t    ); break;
            case 't':                   va_arg( args, ptrdiff_t ); break;
            default:                    va_arg( args, int       ); break;
          }
          break;

        case 'f': case 'F': case 'e': case 'E': case 'a': case 'A': case 'g': case 'G':
          if (p[-1] == 'L') va_arg( args, long double );
          else              va_arg( args,      double );  // 'l' and (none)
          break;

        case 'n': case 'p':
          va_arg( args, void * ); // all are pointer types
          break;

        default:
          p = NULL;
          result = -1;
          errno = EINVAL; // Invalid Argument
          break;
      }
    } while (0);

    format = va_arg( args, const char * );
  }

  return result;
}

int multi_vfprintf(
  FILE       * stream,
  const char * format,
  va_list      args )
{
  // In order to print to file we must first print to string
  
  // (1) get the length of the needed string
  va_list args2;
  va_copy( args2, args );
  int result = multi_vsnprintf( NULL, 0, format, args2 );
  va_end( args2 );
  
  // (2) print to the string then print the string to file
  if (result > 0)
  {
    char * s = (char *)malloc( result+1 );
    if (!s) result = -1;
    else if (multi_vsnprintf( s, result+1, format, args ) > 0)
    {
      result = fprintf( stream, "%s", s );
    }
    free( s );
  }
  return result;
}

#define multi_vprintf(format,args)         multi_vfprintf(  stdout,           format, args )
#define multi_vsprintf(buffer,format,args) multi_vsnprintf( buffer, SIZE_MAX, format, args )

int multi_snprintf(
  char       * buffer,
  size_t       size,
  const char * format,
  ... )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start( args, format );
  int result = multi_vsnprintf( buffer, size, format, args );
  va_end( args );
  return result;
}

int multi_fprintf(
  FILE       * stream,
  const char * format,
  ... )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start( args, format );
  int result = multi_vfprintf( stream, format, args );
  va_end( args );
  return result;
}

#define multi_printf(format,...)               multi_fprintf(  stdout,           format, __VA_ARGS__, NULL )
#define multi_fprintf(stream,format,...)       multi_fprintf(  stream,           format, __VA_ARGS__, NULL )
#define multi_sprintf(buffer,format,...)       multi_snprintf( buffer, SIZE_MAX, format, __VA_ARGS__, NULL )
#define multi_snprintf(buffer,size,format,...) multi_snprintf( buffer, size,     format, __VA_ARGS__, NULL )


int main()
{
  const char * s = "worlds alive";
  
  int n = multi_printf(
    //format string  //arguments
    "%s ",           "Hello",
    "%.5s%c",        s, '!',
    " -no-specs- ",  
    "%d",            17,
    " %f\n",         3.14159265
  );
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) printf( "-" );
  printf( "%d characters printed\n", n );
}
```

#### Caveats

Both of these solutions have a significant drawback: C compilers have code in them to check that `printf`-family functions have the correct number and type of arguments to match the format argument.

Neither of the above versions can do that. So if, for example, you mis-match the *types* of arguments, you are SOL.

Comment: Fair point about modern compilers not being able to check the format specifiers of this new iprintf. I suspected a trailing null would be required, thank you for confirming that is how it would have to be. I don't find that requirement to be as offensive as you do, but obviously there's no accounting for taste ;-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with LOC, what does that mean?

Comment: LOC = Lines Of Code. The macros work by passing as _first_ argument the _number of arguments_. The problem with requiring a trailing NULL is an old one; it isn’t just me who thinks it a bad idea, but there’s history there, but you are right that it isn’t really any more evil than any number of other problems with printf/scanf.

Comment: This is interesting. BUT, it seems like this implementation is overly complex in order to support this pairing of 3 arguments:        "%.5s%c",        s, '!',     but I think this flexibility makes things more confusing. Requiring one format specifier per argument pair seems like a saner version of this idea; after all the whole idea is to avoid having to count variables at the end of a printf statement.

Comment: It would be no less complex to restrict to a single pairing.